# Flutter: flutter_launcher_icons generates deformed icon

Tags: android, ios, flutter, launcher-icon

I am using [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) (0.11.0) to generate my launcher icons. Unfortunately, the result for Android is always deformed:

[image: android icon]

It works fine on IOS:

[image: ios]

Here is my config:

```yaml
flutter_icons:
  android: true
  image_path_android: "assets/icons/android/background.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "assets/icons/android/background.png"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/icons/android/foreground.png"
  ios: true
  image_path_ios: "assets/icons/ios/iconx1024.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21
```

Here are the dimension of the images I used ([imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/323Of.jpg)):

```
background.png (512x512)
foreground.png (390x390)
// For IOS I am using a combined image:
iconx1024.png (1024x1024)
```

I am testing on an emulator (Pixel 3 API 31).
I have tried going the "native route" by just copying the images from [icon.kitchen](https://icon.kitchen/) and that works. However, I am under the impression that this should not be necassary with flutter_launcher_icons.

How do I make the Android icon work properly with **flutter_launcher_icons** ?